# Is it possible to write a VBA macro that runs outside of Excel, and opens an .xlsx file and saves it as a .xlsb file?

Tags: excel, binary

The problem I'm having is the size of the spreadsheet. It's over 36 Mb and I have to ftp the file from the Unix server to the Windows NT network folder.
Space is at a premium, and the same spreadsheet saved as a binary spreadsheet is only 412 Kb. Because I'm manually opening the SS and doing a save as .xlsb, I cannot put it into a scheduler to run in production.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is possible.  I'd write a .vbs script and then have task scheduler run the .vbs file.